# Bash: find with -depth and -prune to feed cpio

Tags: bash, find

I'm building a backup script where some directories should not be included in the backup archive.

```
cd /;
find . -maxdepth 2 \ 
    \( -path './sys' -o -path './dev' -o -path './proc' -o -path './media' -o -path './mnt' \) -prune \
-o -print
```

This finds only the files and directories I want.

Problem is that `cpio` should be fed with the following option in order to avoid problems with permissions when restoring files.

```
find ... -depth ....
```

And if I add the `-depth` option, returned files and directories include those I want to avoid.

I really don't understand these sentences from the find manual:

```
-prune True;  if  the  file is a directory, do not descend into it. If
              -depth is given, false; no  effect.   Because  -delete  implies
              -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

Comment: There is an negation operator in `find` which you can add. Something like `find … -depth … -not -path `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quoting a passage from this tutorial which might offer better understanding of `-prune` option of `find`.

> It is important to understand how to prevent find from going too far.
>   The important option in this case is `-prune`. This option confuses people because it is always true. It has a side-effect that is important. If the file being looked at is a directory, it will not travel down the directory. Here is an example that lists all files in a directory but does not look at any files in subdirectories under the top level:

```
find * -type f -print -o -type d -prune
```

> This will print all plain files and prune the search at all directories. To print files except for those in a Source Code Control Directories, use:

```
find . -print -o -name SCCS -prune
```

> If the -o option is excluded, the SCCS directory will be printed along with the other files.

[Source](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Find.html#toc-uh-16)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't solve my problem. I'll post my question in the Unix & Linux section.

Comment: -prune is basically useless in combination with -depth, since it's only applied after you've already visited all of the children.